# I need to refer to ref parameter with dynamic name from vue template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
        <div v-for="i in 4" :class="(images[i] === null) ? 'not-removable' : 'removable'" class="img">
            <input style="display: none"
                   type="file" 
                   @change="selectImg(i, $event)"
                   accept="image/*"
                   :ref="'imgInput' + i">
            <button class="img-button" 
                    @click="$refs['imgInput' + i].click()">+</button>
            <img src="#" :id="'img' + i"> 
            <div class="delete" @click="deleteImg(i, $event)">x</div>       
        </div>
```

I need something like that, but there is an error in `<button/>` area which says

> TypeError: $refs[("imgInput" + i)].click is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: How to debug this? (this will help you down the path).

You can do a simple `console.log(this.$refs)` to check out how the `refs` are structured in your component.

Now to the answer. Whenever you use `refs` inside `v-for` Vue will create an array. You can access what you are expecting to access by:

```
$refs[("imgInput" + i)][0].click()
```